# How long can raw fish be kept if it has been thawed in the refrigerator?

Tags: fish, storage, spoilage, thawing

I bought fish, repackaged and froze it immediately when I got home. My husband thawed it in the refrigerator (without my knowledge) for 2-3 days. I was afraid of the possibility of food poisoning and refused to eat it. He became really angry, saying the fish was 'just fine' and I was wasting good food. How long can you safely keep previously frozen fish thawed before eating it?